# Fast Python Short DNA String Comparison

Tags: python, alignment, dna-sequence

I have an 8bp string `testStr`

`ACTGACTG`

I want to compare it against a green list of 8bp strings `greenList`.

`GGCGCATG`
`ACTGAAAT`
`ATGCCCGT`
`ACTGAGTG`

If `testStr` is within hamming distance 1 (has a difference at <= 1 position) of any string in `greenList` I want a for loop to proceed. Below is an acceptable match because the sequences differ at only one position.

`ACTGACTG`

`||||| ||`

`ACTGAGTG`

My first attempt to do this centered around creating a green list containing all possible hamming distance 1 variations for the strings in greenList... For example the sequence `GGCGCATG` yields the following hamming distance 1 variations.

AGCGCATG
CGCGCATG
TGCGCATG
GACGCATG
GCCGCATG
GTCGCATG
GGAGCATG
GGTGCATG
GGGGCATG
GGCACATG
GGCCCATG
GGCTCATG
GGCGAATG
GGCGTATG
GGCGGATG
GGCGCCTG
GGCGCTTG
GGCGCGTG
GGCGCCAG
GGCGCCCG
GGCGCCGG
GGCGCCTA
GGCGCCTC
GGCGCCTT

If any of the above sequences directly match "testStr" the loop would proceed.

But there must be a better way to do this...  I also know there are a wealth of alignment algorithms available for DNA alignments.  However, most that i have found seem like overkill for this simple situation.  Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: so `greenList` contains all possible combination of 8-character strings?

Comment: No green list contains a set number of combinations (for example 3).  I want to know if testStr is within hamming distance 1 of any of the three strings in greenList.

Comment: But you're looking to calculate the distance with any variation of a given string in `greenList`, right? Or is it just between 'ACTGACTG' and the three sequences in `greenList`. I don't get why you tried by "creating a green list containing all possible hamming distance 1 variations for the strings in greenList..."

Comment: Yes, with the restriction that we are only interested in variations with <= 1 difference.  let me try to clarify the question a bit more....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to generate all variations of your `green` list. Instead you can calculate the actual hamming distance between your input sequence `x` and each sequence in `green`.

I was about to provide a solution which encoded the string sequences into lists of integers *but* it will work perfectly with strings as is, since strings are iterable!

Therefore, we only need to implement a hamming distance function, which will count the number of dissimilar characters between two given strings. This will do:

```
def hamming(s1, s2):
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

Then we can iterate over `green` and only keep elements with a distance to `x` `<= 1`:

```
x = 'ACTGACTG'
green = ['GGCGCATG', 'ACTGAAAT', 'ATGCCCGT', 'ACTGAGTG']

res = [s for s in green if hamming(s, x) <= 1]
```

*Thank you [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10760768/daniel-hao) for the correction!*